# Dynamic opacity line drawing in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am doing a project with graph (VB.NET) . I am drawing a line handling dynamic property ( opacity changes based on DB value). I don't know how to change the opacity .Help me to find...

Answer (score 1):

When drawing a line, set the color of the brush using an alpha value:

```
Using b As New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, Color.Red))
    Using p As New Pen(b)
        p.Width = 5
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, 10, 365, 110, 365)
    End Using
End Using
```